# Getting difference in mouse movement using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

**I'm wondering if there's a simple way to get the difference in mouse movement using JavaScript.** 
What I mean by this is, if the user moves the cursor 5px to the right, a variable's value would be set to 5, and if the user moves the mouse to the starting location, the variable would be zero. This would also mean that if the user moved the cursor to the left of the starting position, it would result in a negative value. It would also be great to make another variable for the cursor's Y position.
 This would be done with `event.clientX` and `event.clientY;`
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    console.log('X: ' + e.clientX);
    console.log('Y: ' + e.clientY)
})
```